# What is the purpose of the '.' operator in a firebird database query?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

When I am executing the SQL query below against A Firebird database (version 3.0.9) running on a Windows 10 64 bit PC.

```sql
SELECT * FROM AliasName WHERE AliasId=3. or 1=1--
```

I expected the query to fail with an error, but strangely Firebird executes the query without any problem and returns all the three rows in the 'AliasName' table

I searched Google regarding the usage of the '.' operator in Firebird, but couldn't find anything that relates to the issue I am facing.

Comment: Maybe `3.` means just number three with decimal point?

Comment: Also double minus at the end of query is an inline commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot is not an operator, it is the decimal separator. This is SQL standard syntax for an exact numeric literal, and Firebird follows that syntax here. Quoting from the ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016 ("the SQL standard"):

```
<exact numeric literal> ::=
  <unsigned integer> [ <period> [ <unsigned integer> ] ]
  | <period> <unsigned integer>
```

This production rule makes `3.` as valid as `3`. In other words, it allows you to specify the decimal dot without specifying any digits after the dot. This is also not specific to Firebird, most if not all SQL implementations apply this syntax rule.

This is also specified in the section [*Number literals*](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-commons-number-constant) of the chapter *Common Language Elements* in the *Firebird 3.0 Language Reference*:

| Format | Type |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| `<d>[<d> …​] "." [<d> …​]` | NUMERIC(18, *n*) where *n* depends on the number of digits after the decimal point |

The difference is that in Firebird the literal `3` is typed as an `INTEGER`, while `3.` is typed as a `BIGINT` (or `NUMERIC(18, 0)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for your detailed response